My cat has something like a dead nail
My cat has this under the nail, is this something that should concern me?

That looks entirely normal to me; a normal nail above and a callus below. I'm not sure what you are concerned about.

does your cat show any signs of pain when extending the claw or when walking?

When I am touching that looks like she has some pain

If it is significantly different from how she reacts when you touch other toes/claws, I'd say consider a visit to the vet. But most cats object to having front paws handled unless you train them to accept that. (Worth considering since it makes trimming claws easier, though the cat will think you're a weirdo with a foot fetish.)

It might help if you posted a version of the photo with an arrow added to point to exactly what it is you are concerned about, or if you added more description of the issue to help us understand your concern. As things currently stand, we are guessing, and it's hard to be sure what you are concerned about. As I say, I am not seeing anything unreasonable in that picture, but it is possible I'm missing something.

Digression but: the way I usually found out that my cat's tendonitis was bothering her was when she started using her tail as a cushion for her front paws rather than resting them directly on a hard surface.
